# I need to make a .MP4 file with the XVID codec. and i simply can't find a way to do it

Tags: video-conversion, codec, mpeg

My client wants 2 files: .avi and .mp4 in 1080p with the XviD codec.

The .avi was easy, I installed the XviD codec from the official website and exported the .avi using After Effects.

The .mp4 on the other hand is giving me problems.

I tried multiple converters and software to do it but all don't seem to have the option. The software I tried includes: After Effects, Wondershare, Freemake, Media Encoder, MPEG Streamclip, QuickTime Pro, VLC, Movavi, and others that I forgot. Most have the option to export to XviD but only in .avi.

Now I'm questioning if it's even possible. If anyone has the answer I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I think it's not possible, xvid is not supported for MP4.

Comment: Why isn't it? I thought Xvid is just a MPEG4 profile.

Comment: @user1686 the container format **.mp4** and **MPEG4** compression format is completely unrelated different things. *mp4* is a container, which contains file elements, like video file, audio file, chapter markers and subtitle etc..

Comment: @user931000 XviD can be inserted inside mp4 and mkv containers

Comment: @FokkeMars try VirtualDub or VitualDub mod or Nandub

Comment: @Vishwa: I'm aware of that, and you missed my point entirely. If the MP4 container can hold MPEG-4 video, and Xvid is a variant of MPEG-4, then why cannot the MP4 container hold Xvid video?

Comment: @user1686 It can.

Answer (score 1):

MP4 is a container format, and XVID is a codec, so in theory they are compatible.
In practice, for some reason very few converters offer that combination.

I think that [AviDemux](https://www.videohelp.com/software/AviDemux)
can do this.
But even if it can, I'm not sure that it's a good idea to use such a rare combination.

Comment: yeah, the difference between containers and codecs is known to me. I know Xvid uses the mpeg4 standard. you would think that the combination with mp4 would be logical with that but maybe that's just me.

They apparently need it for a beamer, the person i'm emailing with is just a assistant and doesn't know much about it but she told me that both use xvid but only one can play .avi containers and one .mp4 

But thanks for your suggestion. i wil try it!

Answer (score 0):

Since XviD is a video codec and .mp4 is a container format, you can do this. Few years ago there was numerous tools, but seems like they're not available or not in active developments now.

From a quick search, I found few tools, which may be helpful to you, but I can't guarantee it'll be very successful.

My-MP4Box-GUI : [here](https://www.videohelp.com/software/My-MP4Box-GUI)

MP4Tools : [here](https://www.mp4joiner.org/en/)